# Istat menu 3 of Mac equivalent?

Tags: software-recommendation, display, info

With Mac, I have `istat` that shows computer info (memory/cpu/network ...) in real time.

Does Ubuntu have a similar application?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get what you want with [gkrellm](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gkrellm) [image: Install gkrellm]
 -- it works out of the box, but you will probably want to tinker a bit to get the look and the info you're after.

You can install the basic application from the Software Center or via the command line, with `apt-get install gkrellm` , but there are numerous plugins and themes available.

You can see the easily installed plugins with `apt-cache search gkrellm` .  Here's an extract:

```
gkrellm-bfm - system load plugin for gkrellm with a duck
gkrellm-hdplop - A hard drive activity monitor GKrellM plugin
gkrellm-ibam - Advanced battery monitor for laptops - gkrellm plugin
gkrellm-leds - Keyboard LED monitor for GKrellM
gkrellm-mailwatch - GKrellM plugin to watch mailboxes in multiple panels
gkrellm-mldonkey - mldonkey plugin for gkrellm2
gkrellm-radio - FM radio tuner for GKrellM
```

And here's a themes directory (the last time I installed it, this is the site I used to find a theme I liked): [muhri.net/gkrellm](http://www.muhri.net/gkrellm/)

Another option is [conky](http://packages.ubuntu.com/conky)[image: Install conky]

It is also installable from the Software center or via `apt-get`.   It is extremely configurable, and if you search, you'll find many screenshots of customized conky installations.  (Here's one from [conky pitstop](http://conky-pitstop.wikidot.com/g10ii:g-2010-ii)  .)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this question was asked when Unity was brand new and not many people were using it. None of the answers listed make use of the Unity menu bar, which imo is the only worthwhile place to have a system monitor.

Apparently the things in the menu bar are called "Application Indicators" and so far the closest thing I've found to iStat Menus is `indicator-multiload`, explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/40019/10800). In that thread there are also other examples of resource monitors, including one for hardware sensors.

[image: screencap of indicator-multiload]

Answer (score 2):

13 years after this question, since I couldn't find a real alternative to iStat Menus on Linux I had to create one myself.

It's called [Astra Monitor](https://github.com/AstraExt/astra-monitor) and it's a GNOME extension so you need GNOME as your desktop environment to be able to [install it](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6682/astra-monitor/).

Here's a screenshot but you may find more in the GitHub page:

[image: Showing CPU cores usage and other process info]

Answer (score 1):

It's not a direct equivalent, but you can add the System Monitor panel applet, which will show you real-time graphs of CPU, Memory, Network, etc.  Right click on the panel **Add To Panel** and add the System Monitor applet.  Then, right-click on the applet in the panel and in its preferences you can choose which resources to monitor.  It doesn't have a drop-down menu like istat does, but it opens up the full system monitor when you click on it.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [InfoPanel](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/?content=100042) (an screenlet).

[image]

To install this [add the ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/40351#40351) `ppa:screenlets/ppa` and install screenlets and infopanel-screenlet from the software center .

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [conky-faenza](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/conky~meet~faenza?content=133086&PHPSESSID=111fced54abd994675dad2faf33e8843)

[image]

To install first install conky from software center then download [this](http://gnome-look.org/content/download.php?content=133086&id=1&tan=94538081&PHPSESSID=111fced54abd994675dad2faf33e8843) and extract the archive into your home folder and <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and run conky or add it to startup applications.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [indicator-sysmonitor](https://github.com/fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor)

You can easily customize it.

[image: screenshot of <code>indicator-sysmonitor</code>]