# What Application Indicators are available?

Tags: software-recommendation, indicator

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site,** so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here.  While you are encouraged to help maintain its answers, please understand that "big list" questions are not generally allowed on Ask Ubuntu and will be closed per the [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask).

---

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 on one of my systems and I am using the Unity interface. Unity is working quite well so far but I really miss panel applets for net speed, cpu temp, and system monitor.

These applets are useful for viewing quick info. Unlike 10.10, there is no other way to get this info onto the panel or unity launcher. There are solutions like screenlets and conky but they don't feel appropriate for a clean desktop look.

If you know one then please list out any third party indicators with links so that they can be found.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

### [**StackApplet**](http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/stackapplet/)

**Category:** *Other*

StackApplet is a GNOME panel applet that monitors your activity on any StackExchange site.

[image: stackapplet]

[`stackapplet`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/stackapplet) [image: Install stackapplet] in Ubuntu Software Center

---

### For Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04:

Get the latest version as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stackapplet-dev/stackapplet
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install stackapplet
```

---

The first time the application is used, run

```
python /usr/share/stackapplet/stackapplet.py &
```

from a terminal.

Comment: Not available for wily (15.10)

Comment: It is in universal repo as describe above: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=stackapplet&searchon=names

Answer (score 296):

### [**System Load Indicator**](https://launchpad.net/indicator-multiload)

**Category:** *System Information*

Network, memory and cpu usage indicator; this is a port of the original System Monitor GNOME Panel applet (gnome-system-monitor applet).

[image]

In `Preferences` you can customize the output to fit it to your desktop theme:

[image: preferences dialog]

#### To install:

You can install it through the Ubuntu Software Centre by clicking this button:

[image: Install via the software center]

or through the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload
```

If you want the latest updates, you can install it from the PPA with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-multiload/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload
```

Comment: this indicator as it seems, according to this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/720446 that it causes a memory leak in unity. so be aware.

Comment: I would love for the way the scaling of the network throughput works to be a user setting. I prefer a fixed scale rather than the indicator scaling up and down as throughput demands. Other than that, interesting.

Comment: The memory leak bug is when it works in tandem with compiz...so no compiz (which is buggy anyways) equals happy and safe indicator.. :)

Comment: This is the first thing I install on any ubuntu desktop I use. The memory leaks reported appear to have been fixed several years ago. I love being able to see at a glance my cpu and ram usage, network and swap utilization, system load, storage access speeds (R/W) and iowaits. Very helpful in tuning for performance.

Comment: I just installed this and it does not show any icons in the panel, I click on a black square then I can see text output of all the system statuses.  Do I have to do anything in Linux Mint 18.3 cinnamon to get a visual icons in the panel?

Comment: on ubuntu 18.04 this is broken with no updates in years hopefully someone will make it run again - great tool on 16.04 or earlier

Answer (score 132):

## [ClassicMenu Indicator](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/classicmenu-indicator/)

**Category:** Application starter

Provides a simple way to get a classic GNOME-style application menu for those who prefer this over the Unity dash menu. Like the classic GNOME menu, it includes Wine games and applications if you have those installed.

To install Classic Menu indicator in Ubuntu Trusty Tahr:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diesch/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator
```

[image]

Get the most recent version from its [web page](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/classicmenu-indicator/) (PPA available for Ubuntu 11.04, 11.10 and 12.04).

Comment: I'm feeling really stupid, but I can't seem to get this to install. I've added the PPA to my software sources, but what do I need to do to actually install the indicator package?

Comment: @EmmyS You may need to do a : "sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator" after all the other documented steps.

Comment: And it throws an 'E: Unable to locate package classicmenu-indicator'...

Comment: @Frank: run `sudo apt-get update` after adding the ppa

Comment: Perhaps it should be mentioned that as of right now, versions 14.04 and 16.04 , the classicmenu-indicator is available from official Ubuntu repositories ( universe ) .

Comment: Yes, but 14.04 does not contain the latest version.

Answer (score 122):

### [Hardware Sensors Indicator](https://launchpad.net/indicator-sensors)

**Category:** *System Information*

Application Indicator showing hardware sensors.

[image: sensors]

First add the repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:alexmurray/indicator-sensors
```

Update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-sensors
```

Then launch `Hardware Sensors Indicator` from Unity or run `indicator-sensors` from a terminal.

Comment: Shouldn't there be `sudo apt-get update` after the first step? Incidentally, I'm having trouble installing this one. Does one first have to install `lm-sensors`?

Comment: It isn't available for 12.04 through ppa, you will have to download and install manually.

Comment: It isn't available for 13.04 too.

Comment: Just add the PPA for quantal (12.10); works well under raring (13.04).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in 16.04

Comment: Doesn't work on 16.04 LTS. PPA is 404.

Comment: snap install indicator-sensors

Answer (score 109):

### [**Weather Indicator**](https://launchpad.net/weather-indicator)

**Category:** *Weather Forecasting*

**Warning. This indicator is not being updated anymore and will probably not work in current versions of Ubuntu.**
**UPDATE ! Development continues!** https://launchpad.net/weather-indicator/+announcement/11516

Displays the current/extended weather, multiple locations and notifications support.

[image: Weather Indicator]

[`indicator-weather`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/indicator-weather)[image: Install indicator-weather] in Ubuntu Software Centre

or project's PPA: `ppa:weather-indicator-team/ppa`
**Please note!** The latest builds of Weather Indicator *require* updated versions of pywapi, Python Weather API: `ppa:pywapi-devel/ppa`

Comment: This tends to crash quite frequently on 12.04 LTS.

Comment: @Glutanimate It does have that unfortunate habit and occurs with latest version, ofter after resuming from standby. I think it is upstream issue so developer can do little about it. It seems to do it less after switching to the Yahoo feed. [Bugs List](https://bugs.launchpad.net/weather-indicator)

Comment: my-weather-indicator (https://launchpad.net/my-weather-indicator) is better maintained and more stable that this one.

Comment: `There isn’t a software package called “indicator-weather” in your current software sources`

Comment: @NicolasRaoul They have probably removed it from latest Ubuntu releases but as HDave said [**my-weather-indicator**](http://askubuntu.com/a/38004/8570) is a better alternative, it's updated more frequently and is definitely more stable.

Comment: my-weayher-indicator is poorly codded, takes lot of ram and uses high amount of cpu.

Answer (score 96):

### [**CPUFreq**](https://launchpad.net/indicator-cpufreq)

**Category:** *System Information*

[image: cpu-freq-screenshot]

If you have a laptop or Netbook and want to be able to cool down that chip that's burning your hand and save some battery power this will be useful.

`sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq`

OR
[image: Install via the software center]

If you don't use the indicator plugin (say, on Xfce), you can also use this utility in the systray (or notification area).

Comment: Does this applet show policy of just one CPU core or all of cores?

Comment: @eigenein did you get the answer for ur question?

Comment: @ragu.pattabi no

Comment: indicator-cpufreq appears not to work with Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: The PPA threw a 404 for me when I tried to add it, but it turns out is was already in the repos for 12.04, so I installed that and it appears to be working just fine.

Comment: The PPA is no longer needed, the indicator comes with Ubuntu 12.04.  It also does work (but you need to start it manually, such as by typing indicator-cpufreq on a terminal)

Comment: Great is it also included by default in 13.04? How to start it?

Comment: Apparently it's not in the repos for 15.04 :P

Answer (score 78):

### [**My Weather Indicator**](https://launchpad.net/my-weather-indicator)

**Category:** *Weather Forecasting*

this is an indicator that will show weather information in your area, as well as other valuable information such as time of sunrise, sunset and moon phase

[image]

Find out whether you need to wear a jacket, a t-shirt or a waterproof suit... If you click on the indicator, you will get more information about, humidity, dew point, feels like, wind velocity and wind direction, weather condition.

My-Weather-Indicator informs you about sunrise ans sunset time, and the lunar phase

[image: Information]

You can get the forecast for your area for next three days:

[image: The forecast]

You can get information of the weather of two cities at the same time:

[image: Two cities]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator
```

Comment: Can't find the package. :(

Comment: this looks awesome. try to push this upstream!

Answer (score 68):

### Places Indicator

**Category:** File management

This is a simple indicator that shows common folders and all bookmarks, the indicator updates automatically if bookmark was added or removed.

[image: Places Indicator screenshot]

1. Download the [latest version](https://github.com/shamil/indicator-places/archive/master.zip)
2. Extract the files
3. Run *indicator-places.py*

Comment: This is not the most user friendly installation.

Comment: If you want this in your laucher bar as a quicklist menu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/43150#43150

Comment: to actually install: 3. add the path to indicator-places.py to the startup applications (gnome-session-properties)

Answer (score 66):

### [**Caffeine**](https://launchpad.net/caffeine)

**Category:** *Power Management*

Caffeine indicator allows user to temporary disable screensaver/sleep mode, Also there is option to add program in list to disable screensaver permanently for that program.

To install Caffeine indicator in Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/caffeine-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

[image]

Comment: Watch out that caffeine currently has an issue with notify-osd, as all notifications other then critical will be suppressed with caffeine. For further reference see [this bug on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/caffeine/+bug/593649).

Comment: caffein is in the official ubuntu repos since 16.04. so there is no need for that PPA anymore

Answer (score 65):

## [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/downloading?os=lnx)

**Category:** *Cloud Computing*

[image: Dropbox]

Download and install the [deb](https://www.dropbox.com/downloading?os=lnx).

Comment: Cloud Storage rather than Computing... :)

Comment: It's the dropbox, not a isolated indicator....

Answer (score 63):

### [**Redshift**](https://launchpad.net/redshift)

**Category:** *Computer Health*

Redshift adjusts the color temperature of your screen according to your surroundings. This may help your eyes hurt less if you are working in front of the screen at night.

[image: redshift]

[`gtk-redshift`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gtk-redshift)[image: Install gtk-redshift] in Ubuntu Software Centre

**Customise Colour Temperature**

You can change the colour temperature by adding `-t DAY:NIGHT` to the Redshift commmand in **Startup Applications**, here is a popular example:

```
gtk-redshift -t 6500:5500
```

Answer (score 61):

### [VirtualBox™ Indicator](https://launchpad.net/~thebernmeister/+archive/ppa)

**Category:** *Virtualization*

A Python 3 indicator to launch virtual machines.

[image: indicator-virtual-box]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thebernmeister/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-virtual-box
```

Comment: indicator-virtualbox doesn't appear to work in Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: There currently isn't a Precise package. I've installed the Natty package on a new 12.04 install and it's working properly.

Comment: Here a PPA with a version of the indicator for Precise and Quantal: https://launchpad.net/~thebernmeister

Comment: Is there one for Oneiric?

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ You would need to contant [thebernmeister](https://launchpad.net/~thebernmeister/+contactuser) however you could try manually installing the [Precise deb](https://launchpad.net/~thebernmeister/+archive/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=precise) from the PPA.

Comment: Now with i18n. It is translated into Russian at the current moment.

Answer (score 57):

### [**F.lux indicator**](http://stereopsis.com/flux/linux.html)

**Category:** *Computer health*

[image]

f.lux makes your computer screen look like the room you're in, all the time. When the sun sets, it makes your computer look like your indoor lights. In the morning, it makes things look like sunlight again.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kilian/f.lux 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fluxgui
```

**Edit**

This repository is no longer accesible:

"This page does not exist, or you may not have permission to see it."

https://launchpad.net/~kilian/+archive/ubuntu/f.lux

Comment: May not be currently available in ppa form for 12.04.

Comment: Can anybody verify if this is still buggy?

Comment: Also have a look at [RedShift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/)

Comment: +1 for Redshift. Works flawlessly on 12.04 LTS.

Comment: PPA repository no longer exists or marked as private https://launchpad.net/~kilian/+archive/ubuntu/f.lux

Answer (score 56):

## [Shutter](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/shutter/)

**Category**: *Taking and editing screenshots*

[Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) is a program for capturing and editing screenshots

> Shutter is a feature-rich screenshot program. You can take a screenshot of a specific area, window, your whole screen, or even of a website – apply different effects to it, draw on it to highlight points, and then upload to an image hosting site, all within one window.
>   ~ [shutter-project.org](http://shutter-project.org/about/)

To install it, use the [Software Center [image: .install]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/shutter).
Alternatively you can run these commands in a [Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shutter/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install shutter
```

[image: Shutter indicator screenshot]

Comment: What Icon theme is that? It looks pretty cool.

Comment: @Taylor Bioniks(sorry for being late) here it is http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/05/nautilus-elementary-ambiance-theme.html

Comment: Thanks. I figured it was a old post and I was not going to know, but guess I have been proven wrong.

Answer (score 54):

### [Tomate](https://gitorious.org/~natim/natim-tomate)

**Category:** Concentration / Get things done

This is a simple indicator that helps keep concentrated.
You start it before a complicated problem and you have to keep concentrated for at least 10 minutes after it becomes green you can continue to work on your problem but you get thing done.

You can find more information about this concentration technique on the [official website](http://www.pomodorotechnique.com).

Often when you start to work, you continue and tomate give you feedback of the time it took to fix the task.

[image: tomate]

1. Download the [latest version](https://gitorious.org/tomate/natim-tomate/archive-tarball/master)
2. Extract the files
3. Run *tomate.py*

**EDIT:** If direct download does not work the first time, wait a little and try again.  Instead you can also run:

```
git clone https://git.gitorious.org/~natim/tomate/natim-tomate.git
```

**EDIT 2:** You can also install Tomate via the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~stvs/+archive/ubuntu/tomate).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stvs/tomate
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y tomate
```

Answer (score 53):

### [Ejecter](https://launchpad.net/ejecter)

**Category:** *Mounting/Drive Removal*

Handy applet if you are swapping out usb sticks, cards and hardrives on a regular basis.

[image]

You can install [ejecter](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ejecter)[image: Install ejecter] without using the PPA - it's in the default repositories.

Comment: Which theme is that?

Comment: This is no longer available in > 12.10. Any alternative known?

Comment: Looking at the code this will not work in >=12.10 as `libgdu` is no longer available so now needs to use `libudisks2`. For now see [USB Safe Removal](http://askubuntu.com/a/37989/8570)

Comment: The usb safe removal is no longer available, do you know any solution working on ubuntu 13.10 ?

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu > 12.04, try `Bdin`, which can mount/unmount and eject removable devices. It can be found here: https://github.com/fenrrir/bdin. It's a Python script, place it into `/usr/local/bin/` and make executable. Add the launcher to the "Startup applications" in order to start it automatically: run `gnome-session-properties` and enter `/usr/local/bin/bdin.py` in the command field.

Comment: This isn't available in 14.04 anymore :(

Comment: There is always [USB Safe Removal](https://github.com/cas--/indicator-usb)

Answer (score 52):

### [**Sysmonitor Indicator**](https://launchpad.net/indicator-sysmonitor)

**Category:** *System Information*

Nice and simple just shows as text the current processor and ram usage, and also various temperature sensors detected in your system.

[image: indicator-sysmonitor 0.3 with temperature sensors]

`ppa:alexeftimie/ppa` and install package `indicator-sysmonitor`

It is possible to [add own scripts](https://askubuntu.com/a/104883/46531) for customized output:

[image: preferences dialog]

Comment: Is this still supported? I don't see a repo for 13.10 or 14.04 in the ppa

Comment: 14.04 users - http://askubuntu.com/questions/100306/is-an-internet-connectivity-indicator-applet-available-for-the-unity-panel/453975#453975

Comment: How do you get the temperature to show? EDIT: found [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/371922/how-can-i-get-system-monitor-indicator-to-display-temperature)

Comment: Doesn't work on 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 52):

### [**Chars Indicator**](https://github.com/tobyS/indicator-chars)

**Category:** *Other*

Chars indicator is a replacement for the old character applet. It allows you to store characters, which are potentially not available on your keyboard directly, in order to use them conveniently without searching the full chaaracter map (such as fancy unicode chars).

A click on a symbol in the menus copies the selected character to the "middle mouse button" clipboard so it can easily be inserted.

Configuration is really easy: Create a file .indicator-chars in your home dir. Every line in this file represents a set of char (menu items in the main menu) and the single characters are selectable from the corresponding sub-menu.

[image: Screenshot of Chars Indicator in action]

[**Source code**](https://github.com/tobyS/indicator-chars)

Comment: This software have a bug that you can solve before install it. In [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/177934/62483) you'll find the solution.

Comment: There's a slightly "enhanced" (and "fixed") version of this indicator including a deb file here: https://github.com/Sadi58/indicator-chars

Comment: This program supports Python 2 only and may cause a problem when Ubuntu 16.04 ships without Python 2. As such I have ported (or at least tried to port) it to Python 3 in [this fork](https://github.com/adrianiainlam/indicator-chars).

Answer (score 50):

### [Jupiter](http://www.jupiterapplet.org/)

**Category:** *Power management*

#### Discontinued, only works in versions before 13.04.

[(Possible workaround)](http://itsfoss.com/install-jupiter-ubuntu-1304/)

A really helpful power management indicator. You can use it to change display settings as well as simple power management schemes, or to disable your touchpad or wifi adapter on laptops.
It can either run with the new applet system, or with the old notification area system.

[image]
This little icon has helped me a lot in keeping my laptop's temperature under control.

Comment: This isn't an indicator (uses the old systray)...

Comment: It should be able to use the indicator system as well.

Comment: Jupiter has now been ported to python and it actually uses an indicator... the screenshot should be updated :)

Comment: Now that CPU frequency monitor doesn't work for Ubuntu 12.04, I think this is the best choice!

Comment: Could you please include a link to the wallpaper you are using? I am sure I have seen it somewhere before but cannot recall where.

Comment: Jupiter is no longer supported in Ubuntu 13.04...

Answer (score 47):

### SSHPlus

**Category:** *Network*

A simple version of SSHMenu with a list of your regular SSH connections (previously called SSHlist). SSHplus supports sshmenu configuration files, and adds the entries automatically.

[image: sshplus]

1. Download sshplus.py from [here](https://bitbucket.org/anilg/misc/src)
2. In Terminal make the file executable and copy to `/usr/local/bin`

   ```
   chmod a+rx sshplus.py
   sudo cp sshplus.py /usr/local/bin
   ```
3. Create a *.sshplus* file in home directory and add ssh hosts - *one
   per line*

   ```
   gedit ~/.sshplus
   ```

   *Configuration example provided [here](http://www.gulecha.org/2011/07/29/sshplus-a-sshmenu-compatible-appindicator/).*

   - Run **sshplus**

   ***Run Command*** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `sshplus.py`

   - Optionally add to Startup Programs list so it runs upon login.

[Source](http://www.gulecha.org/2011/07/29/sshplus-a-sshmenu-compatible-appindicator/)

Comment: The script is pretty easy to modify, btw.

Comment: The link to the configuration example is broken.  Could someone post another or fix the link?

Comment: @AlexanderNikolasGruber [Wayback machine link](http://web.archive.org/web/20130403120440/http://www.gulecha.org/2011/07/29/sshplus-a-sshmenu-compatible-appindicator/)

Comment: Alternatively, try Remmina which provides SSH and virtual desktop:  `sudo apt-get install remmina`

Answer (score 39):

### [**Radio Tray**](http://radiotray.sourceforge.net/)

**Category:** *Multimedia*

A minimalistic radio player that runs in the notification area. One can also add many other radio stations by adding their URLs.

[image]

This package exists in the repositories. `Radiotray`, can be installed with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install radiotray
```

Answer (score 34):

### [**Brightness indicator**](http://code.google.com/p/feedindicator/)

**Category:** *Screen brightness control*

Brightness indicator allows you to control your laptop display brightness with indicator.

Features:

- Clicking the icon shows you all the possible brightness values, to a maximum of 15 steps.
- The current value is indicated with a dot.
- Clicking a menu item sets the brightness to the desired value.
- Scroll wheel event is enabled on the icon. Scrolling up means higher brightness, scrolling down lower.
- Control screen brightness with custom keyboard shortcuts.

To install Brightness indicator in Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-brightness/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-brightness
```

[image]

Answer (score 32):

### [**Syspeek**](https://launchpad.net/~vicox/+archive/syspeek)

**Category:** *System Information*

SysPeek is a system monitor indicator that displays CPU usage, memory usage, swap usage, disk usage and network traffic.

[image: syspeek]

`ppa:emptythevoid/syspeeknew` and install package `syspeek`, with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:emptythevoid/syspeeknew
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install syspeek
```

Update: SysPeek doesn't work properly with recent Ubuntu versions (and it's not available for Ubuntu versions newer than Precise in the PPA above). Recently, Marco Trevisan ported the indicator to GTK3 and added various fixes - more info [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/06/syspeek-indicator-ported-to-gtk3.html). You can download the DEB from [HERE](http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/s/syspeek/).

Comment: Does this ppa not work with 13.10?

Answer (score 30):

### [Netspeed Indicator](https://github.com/mgedmin/indicator-netspeed)

**Category:** *System Information*

A port of the old netspeed GNOME applet.  Shows the current transfer rate directly on the panel.

[image: indicator-netspeed]

[Source Code on GitHub](https://github.com/mgedmin/indicator-netspeed)

Quick build instructions:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtop2-dev libgtk-3-dev libappindicator3-dev git-core
git clone git://github.com/mgedmin/indicator-netspeed.git
cd indicator-netspeed
make
sudo make install
indicator-netspeed &
```

This indicator was packaged as a deb by [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/indicator-netspeed-displays-network.html). You can download it from [HERE](http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator-netspeed/).

Now also available in Webupd8 PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-netspeed
```

Comment: this only shows the icon in xfce panel, not the actual data. kind of useless thus.

Answer (score 28):

### [**Pastie**](https://github.com/fmoralesc/pastie/)

**Category:** *Clipboard Manager*

One of many clipboard managers this is considered to be the pick of the bunch but we will leave opinions to the bloggers as that's their job.

[image: pastie]

`ppa:hel-sheep/pastie` and install package `pastie`, with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hel-sheep/pastie
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pastie
```

Comment: Not available for precise. (Although workarounds are present: http://xubuntugeek.blogspot.de/2012/05/install-pastie-in-xubuntu-1204-precise.html)

Comment: `parcellite` works wonders on precise but there's no indicator. still works just fine with the global shortcut keys. default is `ctrl+alt+h` and `ctrl+alt+p` for preferences.

Comment: `diodon` is wonderful and automatically starts at login. It also has a nice icon that blends well. It's there in hte repos

Comment: Unfortunately, pastie looks abandoned on Github for almost 2 years and several issues left open.

Comment: Indeed, not available anymore. Therefore Glipper is a great alternative in my opinion.

Answer (score 27):

### [**Keylock Indicator**](https://launchpad.net/indicator-keylock)

**Category:** *System Information*

This one shows which key locks you have enabled caps, num, scroll etc.

[image]

`ppa:tsbarnes/indicator-keylock` and install package `indicator-keylock`

Comment: May not be currently available in ppa form for 12.04.

Comment: Is it part of any package in 12.04?

Comment: Hey can someone help me with this?...Does this indicator support this?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/292535/how-to-get-caps-num-scroll-lock-keys-osd-notification

Answer (score 24):

### [**USB Safe Removal**](https://github.com/cas--/indicator-usb)

**Category:** *Mounting/Drive Removal*

A little appindicator for flash drive safe removal.

[image: usb safe removal]

To add this indicator, download & install the [deb](https://github.com/cas--/indicator-usb/releases)

Comment: The link returns a 404, any solution working on ubuntu 13.10 ?

Comment: I have updated the links to point to github repo...

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work on saucy...

Comment: Was a trivial fix so I forked and created new release.

Comment: Awesome! I̶'̶l̶l̶ ̶f̶o̶l̶l̶o̶w̶ ̶u̶p̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶g̶i̶t̶h̶u̶b̶ (no issue tracker), install goes fine, but launching indicator-usb does nothing, any place to look for a log ?.

Comment: Have you got a usb pen drive attached and mounted. Could try removing `~/.config/indicator-usb`. I have enabled issue tracker.

Answer (score 19):

### [**Glipper**](https://launchpad.net/glipper)

**Category:** *Clipboard Manager*

A clipboard manager for the Gnome desktop, it can store text from both keyboard and mouse so you can easily access the clipboard using a hotkey.

[image: glipper]

[`glipper`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/glipper)[image: Install glipper] in Ubuntu Software Centre

Comment: In precise it states that libldap-2.4.2 is outdated, and I should try with a newer version => so I leave it closed.

Comment: `diodon` is a fine alternative

Answer (score 18):

### [Diodon indicator](https://launchpad.net/diodon)

**Category:** *Clipboard Manager*

Diodon is a lightweight clipboard manager for Linux written in Vala which "aims to be the best integrated clipboard manager for the Gnome/GTK+ desktop".

To install Diodon indicator in Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diodon-team/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install diodon
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

### [Disper Indicator](https://code.launchpad.net/~nmellegard/disper/disper-indicator)

**Category:** *Monitor Switching*

Disper-indicator provides a simple user interface for Disper. Disper-indicator detects which monitors are currently connected to the computer and provides options to enable single screens, clone or extended screen configurations.

[image: disperind]

`ppa:nmellegard/disper-indicator-ppa` and install package `disper-indicator`

*This indicator requires [Disper](http://willem.engen.nl/projects/disper/) to be installed*

Comment: Does this work with nVidia drivers?

Comment: I get this error: `E: Unable to locate package disper-indicator`

Answer (score 17):

### [**Recent Notifications**](https://launchpad.net/~jconti/+archive/recent-notifications)

**Category:** *Other, System*

[Wiki article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD)

The Recent Notifications applet displays the recent NotifyOSD notifications and allows you copy the text or a link from a notification. You can also click on a link to open it. There are options to blacklist applications within the applet to hide the associated notifications and set the time limit to show a message.

To install Recent Notifications indicator in Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/recent-notifications
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-notifications recent-notifications
```

[image: screenshot recent notifications]

After installing run <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> `unity --replace`. You will find a little mailbox in the panel.

*[(more info about changing the icon and uninstalling)](https://askubuntu.com/a/105573/46531)*

Answer (score 16):

### [**Touchpad Indicator**](https://launchpad.net/touchpad-indicator)

**Category:** *System*

If you have a touchpad on your laptop that you want to toggle on and off then you will need this.

[image]

`ppa:atareao/atareao` and install package `touchpad-indicator`

Comment: does it work on 11.10? I see it is crashing.

Comment: @ragu.pattabi Comments are not the place for bug reporting. There is a [bug page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/touchpad-indicator) on the [Touchpad Indicator site](https://launchpad.net/touchpad-indicator).

Comment: In case anyone is put off by the bug discussion here, I can confirm that it works well on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 16):

### [Stardate](https://launchpad.net/~thebernmeister/+archive/ppa)

**Category:** *Amusement*

A Python 3 indicator which shows the current Star Trek™ stardate.

[image: indicator-stardate]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thebernmeister/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-stardate
```

Answer (score 15):

### [**Lookit**](https://github.com/zachtib/lookit)

**Category:** *Screen Capture*

Lookit is a screen capture tool that can be used to capture an area or the entire screen. After capturing, you can save it on your desktop or upload to a FTP, SSH server or Imgur.

[image: lookit]

`ppa:lookit/ppa` and install package `lookit`

Comment: Alternatively, you can use Shutter ([install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/shutter)) which does this through a Quick List. Once it's installed, drag it to the Unity panel on the left, and right click the icon - it should have these same options, plus more for capturing windows.

Comment: (Look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/78957/46531) answer.)

Answer (score 15):

### [**Workspaces Indicator**](https://launchpad.net/indicator-workspaces)

**Category:** *Workspace*

A little indicator to make it easy to switch workspaces.

[image]

`ppa:geod/ppa-geod` and install package `indicator-workspaces`

Note: Does not currently have a 11.10 repository.  See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77160/how-can-i-tell-what-workspace-i-am-in-with-unity/77225#77225) on how to install in 11.10.

Answer (score 15):

## [Indicator-sysload](https://gist.github.com/982939)

**Category:** *System Information*

indicator-sysload is an Ubuntu appindicator that displays the system load (CPU, memory usage, network traffic)

[image]

[**Source Code**](https://gist.github.com/982939)

Comment: (indicator-sysload:10803): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_new_string: assertion `g_utf8_validate (string, -1, NULL)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: looks nice, but not straight forward to install!

Comment: How to install .c file ???

Comment: and how should we install this?

Answer (score 14):

### [**Update Manager**](https://askubuntu.com/a/114996/22263)

**Category:** *Other, System*

Indicator-updatemanager is small update indicator in system-tray that informs about available updates. It will disable the annoying popup ‘Update Manger’ window.

[image]

The Webupd8 PPA has built this for Ubuntu Precise 12.04 and Oneiric 11.10. So as an alternaive, Ubuntu 12.04 and 11.10 can add the PPA and install it by executing following commands in terminal:

> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8`
>   `sudo apt-get update`
>   `sudo apt-get install indicator-updatemanager`

Run application by:

> `update_indicator`

Comment: This does not work on ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 13):

### [Clipit](http://clipit.rspwn.com/)

**Category:** *Clipboard Manager*

A Parcellite fork that uses an Ubuntu appindicator and also comes with some other fixes and improvements.

`ppa:shantzu/clipit` and install package `clipit`

Comment: In Ubuntu 12.04: sudo apt-get install clipit. No need to add ant repository :)

Answer (score 13):

### [Indicator Stickynotes](https://launchpad.net/indicator-stickynotes)

**Category:** *Utilities, Other*

An indicator to add Sticky Notes capability to Unity desktop. Can add multiple notes, hide them all or show them at the same time.

[image: Desktop with StickyNotes]

To install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:umang/indicator-stickynotes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-stickynotes
```

Answer (score 12):

### [**Battery Status**](http://live.gnome.org/BatteryStatus)

**Category:** *System Information*

An applet capable of displaying detailed information about the battery.

`ppa:iaz/battery-status` and install package `battery-status`

To run Battery Status as an indicator applet in Ubuntu: [*(More Info)*](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/battery-applet-status-ubuntu/)

`/usr/lib/battery-status/battery-status --indicator`

Comment: The 'More Info' links work but the content of that website doesn't work in ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04!

Answer (score 11):

## [Window-List](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejwigley/+archive/window-list)

**Category**: *Other, Window Management*

Window-list displays a list of current open desktop windows. Windows can be activated by selecting them from the menu list.

[image: window-list light theme]
[image: window-list dark theme]

Windows-List is available for all versions of Ubuntu running Unity.

install via ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jwigley/window-list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install window-list
```

deb package is also available from the [launchpad repository](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejwigley/+archive/window-list).

run application by:

```
window-list
```

Answer (score 10):

### [Skype indicator](http://www.skype.com/)

[image: Screenshot]

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Comment: Ah, if only the Skype icon were colorless so as to look good!

Comment: hehe. Yes you are right. Anyway I don't know how to do it

Comment: It is the skype, not a isolated indicator...

Answer (score 10):

Prime Indicator is a small, helpful Ubuntu AppIndicator for Nvidia Optimus users running Ubuntu 14.04 which allows users to quickly switch between Intel and Nvidia graphics cards.

[image]

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install prime-indicator
```

Answer (score 9):

### [**Google Reader Indicator**](http://www.atareao.es/)

**Category:** *RSS Feeds*

***UPDATE: Google Reader is now discontinued.***

Google Reader Indicator displays the number of unread items in your Reader account along with article title and excerpt. Click on an article will open it in your default browser.

`ppa:atareao/atareao` and install package `google-reader-indicator`

Comment: Well Google Reader is off to its silent grave...any other indicator that notifies other feeds - Liferea, for example?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/feedindicator/ Lightweight indicator, opens news in browser.

Answer (score 9):

### [**Haguichi Appindicator**](http://www.haguichi.net/)

**Category:** *Networking*

[image]

This applet provides indicator support to Haguichi, a popular Hamachi GUI for Gnome.

`ppa:webupd8team/haguichi` and install package `haguichi-appindicator`

Answer (score 8):

### [**Glippy**](https://launchpad.net/glippy)

**Category:** *Clipboard Manager*

A simple clipboard manager for Ubuntu that provides clipboard support for history, images, text and more.

[image: glippy]

`ppa:bikooo/glippy` and install packages `glippy` & `glippy-ubuntu-mono`

Answer (score 8):

Sound Switcher Indicator allows for easy switching of the default sound input ("source" in PulseAudio terms) and output ("sink") with just a couple of clicks:
[image]

In order to install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yktooo/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sound-switcher
```

After that simply find and run **Sound Switcher Indicator**.

Comment: this indicator is a life saver when using a DAC!

Answer (score 8):

## [Stock Quotes Indicator](https://launchpad.net/~ce3a/+archive/indicator-stocks)

**Category:** network, finance

`indicator-stocks` is a simple stock quotes indicator.

You can click on a menu item to see the stock chart in a browser.

[image: indicator-stocks screenshot]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ce3a/indicator-stocks
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-stocks
```

[source code](https://github.com/ce3a/indicator-stocks)

Answer (score 8):

## [Psensor](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejfi/+archive/ppa)

Psensor is a tool to monitor hardware temperature that integrates nicely with Unity by using an Unity Launcher counter which displays the enabled temperatures as well as an appindicator that you can use to take a quick look at all available hardware temperatures or cpu usage.

Psensor can monitor:

- motherboard and CPU temperatures
- the temperature of Nvidia GPUs
- experimental ATI/AMD GPUs temperature monitor (not enabled for the Ubuntu PPA as it requires compilation using libatiadlxx)
- hard disk drives temperature
- fan speed
- CPU usage

[image]

Plug-ins installation:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors hddtemp

sudo sensors-detect

sudo service module-init-tools start
```

Psensor installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jfi/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install psensor
```

Answer (score 7):

### [**Mounty**](http://skss.learnfree.eu/)

**Category:** *Mounting/Drive Removal*

Mounty is a very simple indicator applet you can use to mount CD / DVD images. It supports ISO, IMG, BIN, MDF and NRG and besides mounting, it can also burn the images to a CD/DVD.

<strike>`ppa:tldm217/tahutek.net` and install package `mounty`</strike>

Follow the directions on this page: https://launchpad.net/mounty

> You can get the .deb package by running
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.learnfree.eu/repository/skss / #SKSS"
> wget http://download.learnfree.eu/repository/skss/repo.pub.asc -q -O- | sudo apt-key add -
> sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install mounty
> ```
>
> This is the official Mounty repository

The original PPA no longer works for some reason but this did the trick.

Comment: if only it supported .DMG files as well it would be perfect.. :)

Answer (score 7):

### [**DesktopNova Indicator**](https://launchpad.net/indicator-desktopnova)

**Category:** *Wallpaper Control*

[image]

This applet works in tandem with the wallpaper changer [DesktopNova](http://sites.google.com/site/haliner/desktopnova).

`ppa:michael-astrapi/ppa` and install packages `desktopnova` & `indicator-desktopnova`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Next,previous,preference don't work.

Comment: @binarylife Did you install DesktopNova? You can report a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-desktopnova/+filebug)

Comment: Ohh sorry, I didn't notice DesktopNova's link, I've just added the PPA and installed the indicator.Thx for your response.

Answer (score 7):

### [**DisPlex**](http://sourceforge.net/p/displex/home/)

**Category:** *Window Manager Switching*

[image: displex]

Displex provides similar functionality to "fusion-icon" but provides a lot more features. It can control window decorations, screen rotation through Xrandr, switch between Metacity or Compiz compositing, provide AcerHK support and more.

To add this indicator, download & install the [deb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/displex/files/)

Answer (score 6):

### [**Feed Indicator**](http://code.google.com/p/feedindicator/)

**Category:** *RSS Feeds*

Panel-based RSS reader. Feed indicator can show RSS feed updates in the Panel via its indicator.

To add this indicator, download & install the [deb](http://code.google.com/p/feedindicator/downloads/list)

Or using a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/indicators
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install feedindicator
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

## SimpleStarter

SimpleStarter is an application starter, based on sshlist. You can launch all programs like putty or rdesktop, not only gnome-terminal, and choose a title for each menu entry.

Download: http://static.bheil.net/geraffel/simplestarter.py

Description at blog post: http://www.bheil.net/blog/2011/07/07/simplestarter-simple-application-starter-appindicator

Answer (score 6):

**CrystalHD indicator**

The indicator shows several states of the crystalhd (Broadcom BCM70012 BCM70015) linux driver: Disabled, enabled, working and error.  
It also lets you disable and enable the driver.

[image: Screenshot of CrystalHD indicator]

- [Google Code Page](http://code.google.com/p/indicator-crystalhd/)
- [Download and instructions](http://code.google.com/p/indicator-crystalhd/source/checkout)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Privacy Indicator can be used to enable or disable:

- Dash online search results;
- Zeitgeist logging (so when you disable
  this, all files you access won't be logged by Zeitgeist and thus,
  will not show up in Dash or any other applications that make use of
  Zeitgeist);
- show real name on the Unity panel.

The indicator also supports clearing the Zeitgeist log and recent files (from the new Nautilus 3.6 sidebar, etc.).

To install it in Ubuntu 12.10 or 13.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diesch/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-privacy
```

More info: [Unity Privacy Indicator: Quickly Enable Or Disable Dash Online Search Results Or Zeitgeist Logging](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/unity-privacy-indicator-quickly-enable.html)

Answer (score 6):

### [Lunar](https://launchpad.net/%7Ethebernmeister/+archive/ppa)

**Category:** *Information*

A Python 3 indicator which displays lunar, solar, planetary, comet, minor planet, star and satellite information.

[image: indicator-lunar]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thebernmeister/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-lunar
```

Comment: Lunar indicator has become even better, because now it can be translated into different languages. It have got English and Russian interface now.

Answer (score 6):

### [Indicator Netspeed Unity](https://github.com/GGleb/indicator-netspeed-unity)

**Category:** *System Information*

Shows the incoming and outgoing network traffic.

Significantly modified [Netspeed Indicator](https://askubuntu.com/a/89889).

[image]

Features:

- Four display modes of traffic.
- Shows how much has been downloaded and uploaded data for the current session.
- Added "Settings" menu. It is possible to change the prefix (KiB/kB/kb), the icon theme, padding.
- Three View mode: Normal, Compact, Minimum.
- For convenience, added option in settings called "Tools" with which you can run terminal utility **nethogs**, for a more detailed analysis of the traffic source. To close nethogs press CTRL+C, otherwise it will run in the background.
- Available multi-languages (you can [add more or correct](https://translations.launchpad.net/netspeed-appindicator/)).

[Source Code on GitHub](https://github.com/GGleb/indicator-netspeed-unity/)

Installation in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fixnix/netspeed
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-netspeed-unity
```

After installation, you can run indicator. The launcher is located in the main menu under «Internet» under the name «Indicator netspeed-unity». Indicator when the installation is prescribed in startup, so after the restart run itself.

Answer (score 5):

### [**syno-indicator**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/synoindicator/)

**Category:** *Download*

Provides an App-Indicator for you Synology NAS. 
Add links and torrents, see download progress, auto-add torrents from a folder.
Only useful if your platform supports App-Indicators and you own a Synology NAS!

[» download from sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/synoindicator/files/)

Answer (score 5):

### [**Unity Launcher Toggle**](http://napdivad.com/unity_launcher_toggle/)

[image]

An appindicator for toggling the Unity launcher mode (fixed or autohide).

Comment: How can I get this Unity Launcher Taggle indicator to show up? What do I need to install or run? Thanks. The link to the project page is dead.

Answer (score 5):

### [PPA Download Statistics](https://launchpad.net/~thebernmeister/+archive/ppa)

**Category:** *Reporting*

A Python 3 indicator which shows the download counts for PPAs.

[image: indicator-ppa-download-statistics]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thebernmeister/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-ppa-download-statistics
```

Answer (score 5):

[HackerTray](https://github.com/captn3m0/hackertray)

Category: Other/Hakernews

HackerTray is a simple Hacker News Linux application that lets you view top HN stories in your System Tray.

[image]

[Installation steps](https://github.com/captn3m0/hackertray#installation) :

```
sudo pip install hackertray
OR 
sudo easy_install hackertray 
OR
#Download Source and cd to it
sudo python setup.py install
```

After that, you can run hackertray from anywhere and it will run.

Alternative:

```
sudo apt-get install python-appindicator python-pip
sudo pip install hackertray
```

After installation open terminal and run indicator with this command "`hackertray &`" without quotes.

To make HackerTray indicator run by default hit <kbd>Super</kbd> key and type Startup Applications and launch it, in opened window click `add` and enter `name` and `command`:

Name: `Hackertray indicator`

Command: `/usr/local/bin/hackertray`

[image]

And press `save`, now log out and log in back. Done.

Answer (score 5):

## Synapse Indicator

Indicator Synapse, a search indicator made by Tom Beckmann for elementary OS. The indicator is similar to Mac OS Spotlight. It creates virtual index of files and items which are on the system. It is designed to access files and items quickly. It also has ability to search in online dictionary/knowledge engine (WolframAlpha) and web.

To install Synapse indicator in Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/indicators
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-synapse
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://github.com/sagarchalise/My-Ubuntu-Unity-Indicators) are some of the indicators I wrote. They are single files based on python for [guake](http://guake.org) and [gpaste](https://github.com/Keruspe/GPaste).

There is also a [calendar indicator for Nepali](https://github.com/sagarchalise/nepcalindicator) i.e. my native country.

Answer (score 4):

### [Indicator Systemtray Unity](https://github.com/GGleb/indicator-systemtray-unity)

for Ubuntu 14.04 - 16.04

**Category:** *System*

[image]

Indicator, when clicked, shows the tray.

[image]

Also there is a display mode "separately from the indicator" - on top of the panel like a dock. In this mode, the position can be changed by scrolling the mouse over the indicator. To change the mode position: press the middle mouse button on the indicator.

Installation in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fixnix/indicator-systemtray-unity
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-systemtray-unity
```

You must then log out and again log in using your user.

[Source Code on GitHub](https://github.com/GGleb/indicator-systemtray-unity)

To remove this package (**with its configuration files!!!**):

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove indicator-systemtray-unity
```

Answer (score 4):

## Crypt-folder Indicator

With Crypt-Folder you can manage EncFS folders via this indicator, You can mount, unmount EncFS folders, create new EncFS folders, stores the password in Gnome Key-ring and mounts it at login, change existing EncFS folders password.

To install Cryptfolder indicator in Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cryptfolder-indicator
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### [MiniDLNA Indicator](https://launchpad.net/minidlna-ai)

**Category:** *Network, Audio, Video, Images*

[image]

Indicator to run and stop [minidlna](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/minidlna) [image: Install minidlna] DLNA server providing UPnP/DLNA access to audio, video, and image directories (e.g. for streaming to a DLNA compliant TV set).

Run minidlna with non-root privileges with an easy to edit configuration `minidlna.conf` stored in  `~/.config/minidlna`.

This Python application runs with both Python2, and Python3.

Answer (score 3):

[Qnotero](http://www.cogsci.nl/software/qnotero)

**Category**: Academic

Qnotero is a quick access panel to your [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org) library, an open source reference manager.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:smathot/cogscinl
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qnotero
```

Answer (score 3):

[GIS Weather](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gis-weather/)

[image]

Features:

- View weather for several days
- Detailed weather forecast for today and tomorrow
- Fast switching between cities
- Select the background and theme weather icons
- "Compass" with the wind direction, with adjustable angle of rotation
  highlighting the high wind
- Supported weather services:

  *Gismeteo.com*

  *AccuWeather.com*

  *OpenWeatherMap.org*

  *Yr.no*
- Support SVG and widget scale
- Indicator to panel
- Presets

To install GIS Weather in Ubuntu 15.10 Wily/15.04 Vivid/14.04 Trusty/12.04 Precise

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gis-weather
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Script Runner](https://launchpad.net/%7Ethebernmeister/+archive/ppa)

**Category:** *Utility*

A Python 3 indicator allowing a user to run a terminal command or script from the indicator menu.  Additionally, a command/script can be run in the background and the output text shown adjacent to the indicator icon.

[image: indicator-script-runner]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thebernmeister/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-script-runner
```

Comment: Nice! Was thinking about something like this, but no need anymore :)

Comment: If this is a tool that written by you, please say so in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> #### [image]    [@ The Killer @](https://www.aerofs.com/)

If you want video tutorial [**Jupiter Broadcasting**](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/37056/bittorrent-sync-vs-aerofs-las-s26e10/)

[Peer To Peer (P2P) Sync and Share Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294916/peer-to-peer-p2p-sync-and-share-ubuntu/295103#295103)

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Indicator

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### [Fortune](https://launchpad.net/~thebernmeister/+archive/ppa)

**Category:** *Amusement*

A Python 3 indicator which calls the *fortune* program and shows the result in the on-screen notification.

[image: indicator-fortune]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thebernmeister/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-fortune
```

Comment: Got a Russian interface now. Additional fortunes can be found in the repository for the different native languages.

Answer (score 2):

### [Indicator-xkbmod](https://github.com/sneetsher/indicator-xkbmod)

**Category:** Accessibility

Keyboard modifiers state indicator for Ubuntu Unity desktop. Unity lacks such accessibility tools which most likely needed when sticky keys is activated.

Icon Mode

[image: indicator-xkbmod icon mode]

Label Mode

[image: indicator-xkbmod label mode]

**Daily Build:** To install add PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sneetsher/one
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-xkbmod
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Tide](https://launchpad.net/%7Ethebernmeister/+archive/ppa)

**Category:** *Information*

A Python 3 indicator which shows tidal information.  The user must craft their own Python 3 script to obtain the tidal data which is then passed back to the indicator for display.

[image: indicator-tide]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thebernmeister/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-tide
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Terran Computational Calendar](https://github.com/terrancalendar/terrancalendar/tree/master/ubuntu_app_indicator)

**Category:** *Date & Time*

Displays the terran computational calendar date.

This calendar system may be useful for mathematicians and programmers due to it's simple algorithm, zero-based numbering, and synchronization with the Unix Epoch.  More info at terrancalendar.com

This app indicator can be [downloaded from github](https://github.com/terrancalendar/terrancalendar/tree/master/ubuntu_app_indicator) or from the links below.

[image: screenshot: terrancalendar.com/app_indicator/screenshot.jpg]

[install: terrancalendar.com/app_indicator/install.txt](http://terrancalendar.com/app_indicator/install.txt)

[app indicator: terrancalendar.com/app_indicator/terran_computational_calendar.py](http://terrancalendar.com/app_indicator/terran_computational_calendar.py)

Answer (score 1):

## Reminder Indicator

Reminder indicator is an indicator app specially designed for Ubuntu to set schedule reminders. These reminders can be configured to play a sound, show a notification, and/or run a command. Indicator Reminder has a powerful date/time selection feature that allows you to express recurring dates/times in plain English. For example: "every day", "every Monday", "every other", "every weekday", "every 30 minutes", and more!. They can also be set to repeat minutely or hourly.

[image]

To install Reminder indicator in Ubuntu Trusty Tahr(tested):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bhdouglass/indicator-remindor
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-remindor
```

or install QT version of Reminder indicator via following commands in Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bhdouglass/indicator-remindor
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install remindor-qt
```

Answer (score 1):

## Tomboy Notes Indicator

Tomboy is a desktop note-taking application which is simple and easy to use. It lets you organise your notes intelligently by allowing you to easily link ideas together with Wiki style interconnects.

To install Tomboy Notes Indicator in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install tomboy
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Calendar Indicator

Calendar indicator is linked with Google Calendar, You can access your Google account calendar via this indicator and get notifications directly on your desktop.

To install Calendar indicator in Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install calendar-indicator
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### [Punycode Converter](https://launchpad.net/~thebernmeister/+archive/ppa)

**Category:** *Utility*

A Python 3 indicator to easily convert a URL between Unicode and ASCII.

[image]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thebernmeister/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-punycode
```

Answer (score 0):

**Live Cricket Score Indicator**:(available for Ubuntu 14.04, 15.04 and 15.10)

**Category:** Other

[Cricket Score Indicator](https://github.com/rubyAce71697/cricket-score-applet) is an App-indicator displays live cricket scores:

Open Terminal and run the commands(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rawcoder/cricket-score-indicator
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cricket-score-indicator
```

Answer (score 0):

### [On This Day](https://launchpad.net/~thebernmeister/+archive/ppa)

**Category:** *Information*

A Python 3 indicator which displays calendar events in the menu.

[image: indicator-on-this-day]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thebernmeister/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-on-this-day
```

Answer (score 0):

### DIY Animated Application Indicator using bash

The only way I know of displaying to the Systray / Application Indicator using bash is with [Indicator-Sysmonitor](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/ubuntu-appindicator-that-displays-bash.html). I used it to create an animated `text-spinner` count down timer:

[image: systray.gif]

Notice the top left of the Systray / Application Notification Area. When bash script starts a spinning text pizza appears beside:

```
Lock screen in: 28 Minutes   Brightness: 450
```

This part of the Systray is generated by a bash script. For more details see: [Can BASH display in systray as application indicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882419/can-bash-display-in-systray-as-application-indicator/882420#882420)